# Dynamic query with NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want create dynamic query (with every word in list create new QueryString and put in QueryContainer[]).  But its not working. I can't create QueryStringQuery and get this error: "The non-generic type Field cannot be used with type". By this website it should work https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/query-string-usage.html

My code is:

```
public IEnumerable<ElasticSearchDocument> Search(int tabId, string textToSearch)
{
 string text = MakeTextToSearch(textToSearch);
 List<string> temp = MakeStrings(text);
 QueryContainer[] querys = null;
     for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
     {
         querys|= new QueryStringQuery()
         {
          Fields = Field<ElasticSearchDocument>(x => x.FullPlainText),
          DefaultField = "FullPlainText",
          Query = temp[i],
          DefaultOperator = Operator.Or
         };
        }
 var searchResults = client.Search<ElasticSearchDocument>(s => s
       .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b
       .Must(querys)
             )
      )
    );
 return searchResults.Documents;
}
```

All working now. I changed:

`querys |= Query<ElasticSearchDocument>.QueryString(x => x.Fields(f => f.Field(c => c.FullPlainText)).Query(temp[i]));`